# Проблема с ссылками на сайте работающем в двух режимах https и http одновременно

Tags: php, html, битрикс

Сайт на битрикс, работает в двух режимах https и http, и есть одна ссылка, она ведет на каталог внутри этого же сайта, href="/services/" по переходу по ней меняется протокол с https на http, все остальные ссылки на сайте ведут себя нормально, если мы зашли по https то переходы происходят без изменения на http, и только одна ссылка меняет. Может кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Без конкретного рабочего примера ничего дельного ответить невозможно, причина может быть в чём угодно

Comment: Если нет какой-то особо веской причины использовать http, лучше от него отказаться и перейти полностью на https. Сразу решится проблема.